# How Do Dielectrics Affect Electric Potential Energy in Capcitors?

Tags: electric-current, potential, potential-energy, capacitance, dielectric

I am currently learning about dielectrics and capacitors in my physics class and part of what I have learned is conflicting.

For starters the book says that capacitors do not interrupt current flow, but then in the textbook it goes onto to say that it does interrupt current flow across the capacitor gap as charge begins to build on the capacitor. Which is it?

Additionally, when learning about dielectrics I learned the following:

$C_0 = \frac{Q_0}{\Delta V_0}$ where 0 represents the situation without the dielectric

and,

$\Delta V = \frac{\Delta V_0}{k}$ where k is the dielectric constant

so,

$C = kC_0$

and then I learned the equation to find the max amount of energy a capacitor can store

$U_e = \frac{1}{2}C_0(\Delta V_0)^2$
but when you add a dielectric I get

$U_e = \frac{1}{2}kC_0(\frac{\Delta V_0}{k})^2$

which evaluates to

$U_e = \frac{1}{2}C_0(\frac{(\Delta V_0)^2}{k})$

which directly oppose what my textbooks says "adding a dielectric results in a proportional increase in energy stored." For $k < 1$ I guess that would be true, but for $k > 1$ it is wrong. Am I messing up the math somewhere?

Comment: I think this might possibly be a duplicate of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105581/energy-stored-in-a-capacitor-with-and-without-dielectric)? Does that address your confusion?

Answer (score 0):

1. Capacitors and Current Flow

The statement that capacitors do not interrupt current flow seems contradictory at first, but it depends on the type of current you are considering. In a direct current (DC) circuit, a capacitor initially allows current to flow as it charges up. Once fully charged, it essentially acts as an open circuit, interrupting the DC current flow. This is because the dielectric in a capacitor (the insulating material between the plates) prevents actual charge flow from one plate to the other.

However, in an alternating current $(\mathrm{AC})$ circuit, the situation is different. In $\mathrm{AC}$ circuits, the current direction changes periodically, which means the capacitor is constantly charging and discharging. This allows AC current to "flow" through the capacitor in a sense, as the charge is continually being moved back and forth between the plates.

2. Dielectrics and Capacitors

Now, let's delve into the equations related to dielectrics in capacitors. You've outlined the standard equations correctly:

- Initial capacitance without dielectric: $C_{0}=\frac{Q_{0}}{\Delta V_{0}}$
- Voltage with dielectric: $\Delta V=\frac{\Delta V_{0}}{k}$
- Capacitance with dielectric: $C=k C_{0}$

For the energy stored in a capacitor, the formula is $U_{e}=\frac{1}{2} C(\Delta V)^{2}$. When a dielectric is added to a capacitor, the capacitance increases to $C=k C_{0}$, and the voltage across the capacitor becomes $\Delta V=\frac{\Delta V_{0}}{k}$.

Substituting these into the energy formula, we get:

$$
\begin{gathered}
U_{e}=\frac{1}{2}\left(k C_{0}\right)\left(\frac{\Delta V_{0}}{k}\right)^{2} \\
U_{e}=\frac{1}{2} k C_{0} \frac{\left(\Delta V_{0}\right)^{2}}{k^{2}} \\
U_{e}=\frac{1}{2} C_{0} \frac{\left(\Delta V_{0}\right)^{2}}{k}
\end{gathered}
$$

Here, it seems you have correctly identified a discrepancy. The energy stored in a capacitor with a dielectric is indeed inversely proportional to the dielectric constant $k$ if the voltage is kept constant. This result seems to contradict the statement that adding a dielectric increases the energy stored in the capacitor.

However, the key to resolving this apparent contradiction lies in understanding the conditions under which these equations apply. The equation you've used assumes that the voltage across the capacitor remains constant when the dielectric is inserted. In many practical situations, especially in capacitors connected to a constant voltage source, adding a dielectric increases the capacitance while the voltage stays the same. In such cases, the energy stored in the capacitor actually increases, since $U_{e}=\frac{1}{2} C(\Delta V)^{2}$, and $C$ has increased due to the dielectric.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a series circuit comprising a battery, resistor, open switch and an uncharged capacitor.
The switch is closed and a current flows in the circuit.
The capacitor "charges up" and eventually the current becomes zero with the potential difference across the capacitor is the same as that of the battery.
In all of this no current actually flows between the plates of the capacitor rather the amount of net charge on each of the plates changes.

---

It depends as to whether or not a battery is connected across the capacitor.

Dielectric added with the voltage across the capacitor constant, ie a battery connected across the capacitor.
Before dielectric (constant $k$) added energy stored $= \frac 12 C_0 V^2$.
After dielectric added energy stored $= \frac 12 k\,C_0 V^2$, ie energy stored has increased.

Dielectric added with the charge stored in the capacitor constant, ie nothing connected across the capacitor.
Before dielectric (constant $k$) added energy stored $= \frac 12 \frac{Q^2}{C_0}$.
After dielectric added energy stored  $= \frac 12 \frac{Q^2}{k C_0}$, ie energy stored has decreased.